# "Comprimir" valores de um array de shorts, para um array de inteiros

Tags: c

Boa noite. Eu tenho que resolver um exercicio para avaliação no qual nao faço ideia de como o fazer. Eu tenho de comprimir 2 valores consecutivos de um array de shorts, para serem guardados num array de inteiros. Isto feito até ao final do array de shorts. (exercicio em C)

Alguém me consegue ajudar, pfv? Obrigada

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer algo como:

```
short a[ ARRAY_MAX_TAM * 2 ];
int b[ ARRAY_MAX_TAM ];

for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_MAX_TAM * 2; i++ )
    ((short*)b)[i] = a[i];
```

Segue um código testado capaz de solucionar o seu problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Quantidade de elementos na array de inteiros */
#define ARRAY_MAX_TAM   (10)

/* Array de shorts */
short a[ ARRAY_MAX_TAM * 2 ] = { 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4 };

int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    int b[ ARRAY_MAX_TAM ]; /* Array de inteiros */

    /* Converte array de shorts para ints */
    for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_MAX_TAM * 2; i++ )
        ((short*)b)[i] = a[i];

    /* Exibe Array de shorts */
    for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_MAX_TAM * 2; i++ )
        printf("%d ", a[i] );
    printf("\n");

    /* Exibe Array de inteiros */
    for( i = 0; i < ARRAY_MAX_TAM; i++ )
        printf("%d ", b[i] );
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3 5 8 9 7 9 3 2 3 8 4 
65539 65540 589829 393218 196613 524293 458761 196617 196610 262152
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Como sou iniciante em C, sinto-me um pouco perdida. Muito obrigada mais uma vez.

Comment: Eu vi seu pi! Muito bom xD